# ODBC with Oracle Trigger Key Column

Tags: oracle, odbc, c#-2.0

I'm trying to update some existing code that is supposed to write data to a variety of Databases (SQL, Access, Oracle) via ODBC, but I'm having a few problems with Oracle and am looking for any suggestions.

I've set my Oracle database up using a Trigger (basic tutorial online, which I'd like to support).

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    RECORDID NUMBER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ID       VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    COUNT    NUMBER      NULL

);
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE TABLE1_SEQ 
GO

CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE1_TRG
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.RECORDID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TABLE1_SEQ.nextval 
        INTO :new.RECORDID 
        FROM dual;
    end;
GO
```

I then populate a DataTable using a `SELECT * FROM TABLE1`. The first problem is that this DataTable doesn't know that the RecordId column is auto-generated. If I have data in my table then I can't alter it because I get a error

> Cannot change AutoIncrement of a DataColumn with type 'Double' once it
>   has data.

If I continue, ignoring this, then I quickly get stuck. If I create a new DataRow and try to insert it, I can't set RecordID to DBNull.Value because it complains that the column has to be non-null (NoNullAllowedException). I can't however generate a value myself, because I don't know what value I should be using really, and don't want to screw up the trigger by using the next available value.

Any suggestions on how I should insert data without ODBC complaining?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a colon before 'new' in the WHEN clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear that your first problem is with an Oracle database. There is no such thing as an "Autoincrement" column in Oracle. Are you sure that message is coming from an Oracle database?

With Oracle, you should be able to provide any dummy value on insert for the primary key, and the trigger will overwrite it.

There is also nothing in your provided description that would prevent you from updating this value in Oracle (since your trigger is on insert only) unless you have foreign key references to the key.

Comment: No, Oracle doesn't support an AutoIncrement, but I need an equivelant of "I don't need to populate this field, Oracle will do it for me" so the DataTable doesn't throw Exceptions. You're correct, I can provide a dummy value, but in the general case I don't know what dummy value is valid... -1? 0?... I only know what the trigger does in my very specific test database. If it were a trigger that generates a String or a Guid, what do I use then? :S

Comment: Setting AllowDBNull obviously was a more useful approach, rather than trying to fit in with autonumbers.